# Load weights from TensorFlow checkpoint to Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a TensorFlow with Keras model and using `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` I've saved the weights as follows:

```
cp_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,
                                          save_weights_only=True,
                                          verbose=1)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[cp_callback], epochs=50, batch_size=256)
```

But while trying to load the saved weights there is nothing changed to my model, after building the model architecture and compile it I load weights as follows:

```
model.load_weights('./checkpoints/cp.ckpt')
```

But nothing happens, the testing accuracy is as random guessing, while my real testing accuracy is 80.49%

The model consists of keras dence layers with l2 kernel_regularizer and glorot kernel_initializer, also I'm using TensorFlow version 1.12.0, any ideas?

Comment: how did you generate those ckpt files? Because keras saves model and weights in HDF5.

Comment: As mentioned in the question I'm using Keras callbacks to create checkpoints and save them as described in the TensorFlow tutorials (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models) in Save checkpoints during training section.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was asking why a ckpt file was generated instead of HDF5. Seems you are using tf.keras and they changed that as well. The docs you linked show that you have to pass checkpoint_path to load_weights, not a .ckpt file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using tf.keras, the checkpoint_path equals to "training_1/cp.ckpt" and in my case is equals to checkpoints/cp.ckpt, so load_weights takes .ckpt file right?

Comment: As I understand the code-snippets, the fact that he uses the ".ckpt" extension is irrelevant. The actual file format will still be HDF5. @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: @KasperFredenslund No, tf.keras can write tensorflow checkpoints, while plain keras only uses HDF5.